# Function overloading with std::function argument: why is the const method never called?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, overloading

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    void doStuff(function<void (const string *)> func) const
    {
        cout << "Const method called" << endl;
        for(const auto& i_string : m_vec)
            func(i_string);
    }

    void doStuff(function<void (string *)> func)
    {
        cout << "Non-const method called" << endl;
        doStuff([&func](const string *str)
        {
            auto mutableString = const_cast<string *>(str);
            func(mutableString);
        });
    }

private:
    vector<string *> m_vec;
};

int main()
{
    auto a = A{};

    a.doStuff([](string *str){
        *str = "I modified this string";
    });
}
```

In this example, the const method is never called.  If the code looks weird, here's what I'm trying to do:

Instead of a getter method, I let clients iterate objects by passing a function. To enable both const and non-const access, I want to provide const and non-const overloads. Further, to avoid copy & paste, I want to implement the non-const method in terms of the const method: the const method in my code is actually more complicated than the one I use here.

Now, my questions is this: If you run this code, it will recursively call the non-const function until the stack overflows. I don't understand why the line `doStuff([&func](const string *str)` in the non-const method calls itself and not the const method.

Answer (score 5):

The non-const method is declared as accepting function that can be called with `string *` argument. The provided function accepts `const string *`. `string *` is implicitely convertible to `const string*`. Therefore the function with `const string *` is acceptable argument for the non-const method and the non-const method is selected because `this` is non-const as well.

Use `const_cast` on `this` to use the const method:

```
const_cast<const A*>(this)->doStuff(…);
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I had a feeling that I was missing something like this, but I couldn't quite put my finger on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `const` overload is only called when an instance of the `A` class is `const`.  This is the case because of the `const` at the end of the declaration:

```
void doStuff(function<void (const string *)> func) const //This const at the end causes
                                                         //The member function to only be
                                                         //called when `a` is const
```

The const-qualifier at the end applies to the `this` object, not to the parameters.  Removing the `const` will cause ambiguity, so use StenSoft's way to get it to work.

Comment: removing `const` would result in ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a correct overload:

```
void doStuff(function<void (const string *)> func) const
```

and

```
void doStuff(function<void (string *)> func)
```

Overloaded functions should have same prototype but different arguments. In your case your const method can only be called if your object is `const`. Here you have just 2 methods that can be called in different situations but these situations are not caused by `overloading` mechanism or any other argument-dependent feature.

Also, why not to let people use your object with default iterators? Implement `begin()` and `end()` methods in your object and let people do everything they want without your interface but std lib interface: they will be able to use ranged-for, some algorithms like `find` and `find_if` and else good things.

Comment: You're correct that this is not formally overloading, thanks for pointing that out. Live and learn. :) I did consider implementing begin() and end(), but my class has more than one collection that could potentially be iterated over, and I want to make that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class always_void, class...Ts>
struct can_apply_helper:std::false_type{};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct can_apply_helper<Z,
  decltype((void)(Z<Ts...>)),
Ts...>:std::true_type{};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=can_apply_helper<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

Trait that detects if a type-expression would represent a valid call:

```
// result_of_t fails to be SFINAE in too many compilers:
template<class F, class...Ts>
using invoke_helper_t=decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Ts>()...) );
template<class Sig> struct can_invoke;
template<class F, class...Ts>
struct can_invoke<F(Ts...)>:
  can_apply<invoke_helper_t, F, Ts...>
{};
```

Now, replacement `doStuff` in your class.  The first one detects if you can call the function with a `std::string const*`:

```
template<class F, class=std::enable_if_t<
  can_invoke< F&(std::string const*) >{}
>>
void doStuff(F&& func) const
{
    cout << "Const method called" << endl;
    for(const auto& i_string : m_vec)
        func(i_string);
}
```

This one detects if you **cannot** call it with a `std::string const*` and that you **can** call it with a `std::string*`:

```
template<class F, class=std::enable_if_t<
  !can_invoke< F&(std::string const*) >{} &&
  can_invoke< F&(std::string*) >{}
>>
void doStuff(F&& func)
{
    cout << "Non-const method called" << endl;
    doStuff([&func](const string *str)
    {
        auto mutableString = const_cast<string *>(str);
        func(mutableString);
    });
}
```

this also removes the needless type erasure of `std::function` in your example, and routes any call that can go to the `const` method to the `const` method.

As an aside, storing a `std::vector<std::string*>` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't really gotten into the more advanced metaprogramming methods, and this is a tad too complex for me right now - and I can also think of other pragmatic solutions to my problem, such as simply renaming the methods.  But you've given me something to think about, thank you!

Comment: @Leander *nod*.  If concepts-lite ever makes it into C++, much of the above becomes ridiculously easier, and we need it to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning may be that a lambda with the signature `void(const string *)` cannot be invoked with a `string *` and hence not converted to a `function<void (string *)>`. This is incorrect because a `string *` is implicitly convertible to a `const string *` and therefore it is perfectly legitimate to construct a `function<void (string *)>` object out of a function object expecting a `const string *`. It is only the obverse case that is not allowed. This means the compiler determines that both argument conversions are viable (with equal rank). This would make the two candidates ambiguous in overload resolution, but because the pointee of implicit `this` is non-`const`, the non-`const` overload is preferred (the rank of the implicit `this` is "exact match" for non-`const` vs. "conversion" for `const`).

The solution, as has previously been mentioned, is making sure the pointee of implicit `this` is `const`. This will eliminate the non-`const` overload from the candidate set and force an invocation of the intended overload.